# How to get extra data from Google Sign-In(web)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-signin

What I want is to get the user gender and birthday (if public) using my Google signin API, but having searched through the references I cannot find how to get any other data other that what getBasicProfile returns. I am using JQuery/JS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="g-signin2" id="my-signin2"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function onSuccess(googleUser) {        
    console.log('Logged in as: ' + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());    
}

function onFailure(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

function renderButton() {
    gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',                   
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
    });
}
```

According to the documentation the **"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"** is supposed to return the birthday, too, but I cannot figure out how to get it.

Comment: I haven't used Google Plus login, but I have done Facebook login, which also uses OAuth, and it's probably to do with the scopes given. You have to request the scopes you want, and different scopes grany access to different data. The user can then see the data that is requested on login and decide whether to continue. It makes sense that date of birth not be exposed by default because it could be used for identity fraud.

Comment: As i mentioned, the scope I am using asks the user to give access to bday, the question is how do i retrieve it afterwards

Comment: I would double check that because that scope looks wrong - it's not usually a URL as far as I can remember. It's normally a single word.

Comment: as i know it can be both, depends on which function you put it.